# Getting error using quintus-all.js

Tags: html, game-engine

I have a problem with animation; here is my code:

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
      var Q =window.Q= Quintus().include("Sprites, Scenes,2D, Anim").setup({maximize:true});

  Q.Sprite.extend('user',{
      init:function(p){
          this._super({sheet:"user",sprite:"user",
              x:p.x,y:p.y,vx:p.vx,vy:p.vy});
      this.add("animation");
  },
  step:function(dt){
          this.play("walk");        
      }     
  });

  Q.scene("scene1",function(stage){
      var sprite1=stage.insert(new Q.user({x:200,y:20,vx:0,vy:0}));
  });

  Q.load("sprites.json,sprites.png",function()
  {
      Q.compileSheets("sprites.png","sprites.json");
      Q.animations('user',{walk:{frames:[0,1],rate:1/15}});
      Q.stageScene("scene1");
  })           
});
```

The error I get is the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'draw' of undefined, quintus-all.js:4185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure you have a spritesheet called "user" in your sprites.json, if you don't you'll get this error.